# react-testing-library or Cypress - Adding multiple data-testids

Tags: javascript, jestjs, cypress, react-testing-library

I have a box that is selectable, so I want to add this box two test ids, one to test the type of the box and the other if it is selected. Should I add two data-testid attributes or two keywords in one data-testid? what is the best practice for this when it comes to Cypress or react-testing-library?

```
<div data-testid="box-user" data-testid="box-user-active">
```

vs

```
<div data-testid="box-user box-user-active">
```

I know there are other ways to check if the box is selected, but there are plenty of other use cases when adding two test ids would make things much easier.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if you can provide two same data attributes in one HTML tag.

Comment: Yes, that does not seem to be valid.

Comment: The test ID should describe what the component *is*, for selection purposes; if you want to add arbitrary information you can use other attributes like `data-value`.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need two test ids. You can reuse the same test id for as many tests as you want.

Answer (score 5):

I've seen posted that `data-testid` and `getByTestId` should be a **last resort** (preferring `getByText` and `getByRole`), and there would lots of opinions about that.

From a purely technical standpoint, given a space-delimited list of values

```js
<div data-testid="box-user box-user-active">
```

you can select by either value with a partial match expression.  Ref [jQuery attribute-selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

The most useful for multiple space separated values is `~=`.

```js
cy.get('[data-testid*="box-user"]')        // either attribute
                                           // plus other variations like "unbox-user"

cy.get('[data-testid~="box-user"]')        // space-delimited (full values only)
                                           // so "box-user" but not "box-user-active"

cy.get('[data-testid~="box-user"][data-testid~="box-user-active"]') // must have both

cy.get('[data-testid^="box-user"]')          // starts with "box-user"
cy.get('[data-testid$="box-user-active"]')   // ends with "box-user-active"
```

Answer (score 1):

For react testing library also allows partial matching: https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#precision

@user14783414 's anwer for react testing library would be...

```
<>
  <div data-testid="box-user box-user-active">
  <div data-testid="box-user box-user-inactive">
</>
```

```
/* Return only first item */
screen.getByTestId('box-user-active', {exact: false})
screen.getByTestId('box-user box-user-active', {exact: true})

/* Return both items*/
screen.getByTestId('box-user', {exact: false})
```